# Visual Studio 2015 deleting test ouput files

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, f#, automated-tests

I am currently working on a small program which prepares the environment for testing (reverts the snapshot of a VM, upgrades our software to latest version, etc) and then launches some automated tests via MSTest.

The tested software creates some files which I copy to my \out folder (defined in Default.testsettings) so that after execution my test launcher can copy them to their final destination. That final destination is not known from my test implementation, thus why I first copy them in my \out folder temporarily.

Unfortunately, the issue I am having is that the contents of that folder is getting deleted at the end of each test. A workaround would be to just use another location for the temp folder, but then I'd have to add a field in an xml configuration file to specify that location, whereas the \out folder is implicitly known by both my test launcher and tests implementation.

What is the reason that this folder/folder's content are getting deleted at the end of my test execution? What can I do to keep them?

Thanks

EDIT: If it makes any difference, I am running the test one by one for now from within VS itself, and not running it in a "deployment" environment with my test launcher that calls mstest, etc.

Comment: If you look in `Default.testsettings`, do you have a Cleanup script that's configured to run once your tests are done? There might be one if you have a big automated tests setup - the deployment files might take too much space after a while. I've tried to reproduce your issue, but the files I create during my tests aren't removed afterwards. =/

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the issue since we don't have any cleanup script in Default.testsettings. We only use the naming scheme for that specific folder, the timeout and deployment settings of that file.